# Create Working Folders using stcmd

Tags: starteam

I have been trying to write an stcmd that checks out code from a StarTeam repository. Here's what the command looks like:

```
stcmd co -p "Username:Password@localHost:1024/Store Server/Store Server/USB/sources/$OEM$/$$/Setup/Scripts"
```

Every time I run this code, I get the following response:

> C:\StarTeam\Store Server\USB\sources\$OEM$\$$\Setup\Scripts\osConfig.ps1 (The system cannot find the path specified)

I'm guessing I need to have to create the working folder's location in order for my check-out command to work properly. Is there a way to create the working folders of a repository using stcmd? I know I can do it through StarTeam, but I wanted to see if it's possible to create it through stcmd so it can create the folders on new computers when my code runs.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which version you're using, but in 5.4 the command to create working directories is:

```
stdcmd local-mkdir
```

so you'd need something like:

```
stdcmd local-mkdir -p "Username:Password@localHost:1024/Store Server/Store Server/USB/sources/$OEM$/$$/Setup/Scripts"
```

This is the answer to your question, but I'm not sure it'll be the solution to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of StarTeam you're using, but in 13.0 at least, there's an option -cwf (checkout working folders) which you can append to the check-out command.  if you also want this to checkout subfolders of said working folders, you can also append -is (include subfolders, maybe?).  So, try:

```
stcmd co -p "Username:password@localHost:1024/Store Server/Store Server/USB/sources/$OEM$/$$/Setup/Scripts/" -cwf -is
```